# Where can I find a version of rpcgen that has MT auto mode?

Tags: 16.04, oracle, rpc

[Oracle's own documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1435/rpcgenpguide-41939/index.html) about `rpcgen` states that it has an `-A` flag which turns on MT auto mode in the generated code.

But on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, rpcgen does not appear to have this option.

Does anybody know where to find a version for Linux which has this?

Answer (score 0):

[The preface page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1435/oncpreface-11/index.html) says the following

```
The Solaris 9 release is the Sun Microsystems distributed computing 
operating environment. It includes SunOS release 5.9 with the ONC+ 
technologies and the Common Desktop Environment (CDE), as well as other 
utilities.
```

I'm going to guess the feature I'm looking for is probably only available in SunOS 5.9.

Fortunately rpcgen comes with the `-M` option on Ubuntu, which generates thread-safe stubs. This still seems a step short of what I think the `-A` flag does though.

I'm not going to accept my own answer yet; hopefully I'm wrong.